# test variable string in xsl

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to test if a variable value equals to some string

```
 <xsl:if test="$str1='rtl'">
```

I know for sure that $str1 value is 'rtl' but the test returns false..
where do I go worng?

thanks

**EDIT:**

well, the thing was that the variable value was '[[dir]]' and there was another (old) code that runs on this xsl file that replaced all those string to 'rtl' or to 'ltr' so the value was 'rtl' but only after the test...  :) / :(

Comment: The test tests the value is 'rtl' so most likely the thing you did wrong is "know for sure that $str1 value is 'rtl'" :-) Are you sure it has no white space for example?

Comment: well, the thing was that the variable value was '[[dir]]' and there was another (old) code that runs on this xsl file that replaced all those string to 'rtl' or to 'ltr' so the value was 'rtl' but only after the test...  :) thanks!

Answer (score 6):

A nice way to debug this is to have

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat($strl, ' =? ','rtl')"/>
<xsl:if test="$str1 = 'rtl'>True</xsl:if>
```

And check the result.